# Get error using chrome.runtime.connectNative() in background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, background

I'm writing an extension for chrome(Version 77.0.3865.90), got an error "**Uncaught TypeError: chrome.runtime.connectNative is not a function**" after trying to use chrome.runtime.connectNative() in background.js, that confused me, because I'm not using it in content.js. Is this function deprecated ?

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Muter",
    "version": "0.1",
    "description": "Mute html5 video with shortkey.",
    "permissions": ["declarativeContent", "storage", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "commands": {
        "pause" : {
            "suggested_key": {
                "mac": "Command+Shift+Z"
            },
            "description": "Pause video"
        }
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
var videoStack = [];
var isVideoPlaying = true;
var port = chrome.runtime.connectNative('video_controler');

port.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
    console.log('Received: ' + response);
});
```

**Host App**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("pause_or_play\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-client): `can only be used if the "nativeMessaging" permission is declared in your extension's manifest file.`

Comment: Yes i see, how stupid i'm, thanks so much !

Comment: Extensions API error messages are quite unfriendly indeed.

Comment: now i got "Unchecked runtime.lastError: Error when communicating with the native messaging host."  :(

Comment: I guess the host app must process stdio as explained in the documentation. Look for examples.

Comment: I installed Native Messaging Example 1.0 from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/nativeMessaging, and it didn't work properly neither.

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome or some antivirus blocking it.